# Como eu faço pra criar uma tabela no stack overflow

Tags: debate

Como eu faço pra criar uma tabela no stack overflow? Por que, sempre que eu crio uma tabela, ela aparece como linha na versão final.

Segue o exemplo:

Carro  preço  cor
Gol   15000  vermelho
uno   14000  azul
corsa 13000  verde

Comment: Veja [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/401803) e [aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716)

Answer (score 6):

Basta formatar a sua tabela como se fosse código utilizando o botão `{}` do editor ou selecionando o conteúdo e pressionando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.

```
Carro    preço     cor
Gol      15000     vermelho
uno      14000     azul
corsa    13000     verde
```

Veja

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode, inclusive, utilizar aplicações de terceiros para formatar melhor a tabela.

- https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Produzindo:

```
+-------+---------+-----------+
| Carro |  preço  |    cor    |
+-------+---------+-----------+
| Gol   |   15000 |  vermelho |
| uno   |   14000 |  azul     |
| corsa |   13000 |  verde    |
+-------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Gosto muito do site https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/. Acho legal utilizar a tabela com os caracteres e não como imagem por causa da acessibilidade. E facilita no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Além das formas já comentadas e respondidas eu recomendo fazer com imagem, quase sempre ficará melhor e mais bonito. [Pode ser visto no final dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101). Ou pode ver só a tabela de outra resposta:

[image: Exemplo de tabela em imagem]